# Widget content isn't showing on pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a standard widget which I've included in my footer with

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

The content of the widget is visible only in categories pages. e.g. `archive.php`.

How can I show it on other pages too? It is included with the footer on all pages, like this:

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

In the footer.php I have

```
<div class="footer-center" data-equalizer-watch>
   <div class="baseline">
       <div class="newsletter">
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE

```
<div class="newsletter">
     <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' ); ?>
</div>
```

Just changed `get_sidebar();` to `dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' );`

Widget function in `functions.php`

```
//Stay Connected widget
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );

function stay_connected_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'stay_connected_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'stay_connected_load_widget' );

class stay_connected_widget extends WP_Widget { 
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct( 
            'stay_connected_widget',  
            __('Stay Connected', 'stay_connected_widget_domain'), 
            array( 'description' => __( 'Social networks and subscribe form', 'stay_connected_widget_domain' ))
        );
    }

    //Widget frontend
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $cf7_form = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['cf7_form'] );
        echo $args['before_widget'];
    //  echo $args['before_title'] . '<h4>' .  __( 'Stay Connected', 'stay_connected_widget_domain' ) . '</h4>' .$args['after_title'];
        ?>

        <?php           
        if(!empty( $cf7_form )){
            echo '<h4 class="form_title">'. __('Subscribe By Email').'</h4>';
            echo '<div class="stay_connected_form">'.do_shortcode(html_entity_decode($cf7_form)).'</div>';
        }       
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    // Widget Backend 
    public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'cf7_form' ] ) ) {
            $cf7_form = $instance[ 'cf7_form' ];
        }
        else {
            $cf7_form = __( '', 'stay_connected_widget_domain' );
        }
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cf7_form' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Contact Form:' ); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cf7_form' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'cf7_form' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $cf7_form ); ?>" placeholder="[<?php _e('contact form shortcode'); ?>]"/>
        </p>
        <?php 
    }
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['cf7_form'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['cf7_form'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['cf7_form'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

Update

```
Array ( 
    [wp_inactive_widgets] => Array ( ) 
    [header] => Array ( 
        [0] => media_gallery-2 
    ) 
    [footer] => Array ( 
        [0] => custom_html-2 
    ) 
    [sidebar] => Array ( 
        [0] => stay_connected_widget-3 
        [1] => search-2 
    ) 
    [array_version] => 3 
)
```

Comment: You are using any theme or create a custom widget?

Comment: It is heavily edited standard theme and custom widget

Comment: I mean it is another directory in themes.

Comment: you can create a widget by function and try to show on a page. if you want to i will provide code

Comment: use dynamic_sidebar function

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do this. On home-page and on archive.php pages is working okay. But on pages created from backend admin panel "Pages->create new" isn't showing.

Comment: Still on one custom page which I've created isn't visible.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: where you added your stay connect widget in sidebar? https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEQMN.png

Comment: Yes, like on the image.

Comment: can you share me a image?

Comment: Yes, here is the image: https://i.imgur.com/XqYdm63.png

Comment: seems your sidebar name is not `sidebar`?

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: It is custom theme of the default one which I'm trying to do.

Comment: `$test = get_option('sidebars_widgets'); print_r($test);` add this code in functions.php and share result here

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in functions.php

```
function stay_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Stay Connected ',
        'id'            => 'stay_connected_widget',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '',
        'after_title'   => '',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'stay_widgets_init' );
```

Use this in footer.php file

```
<div class="newsletter">
     <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'stay_connected_widget' ); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks but I don't understand what I've done wrong.

Comment: you can see `Subscribe By Email` text on frontend?. Im not sure what you have done in functions.php file. you code working fine for me.

Comment: I've got it. `get_sidebar();` was included 2 times on a page and this somehow removes it. Still don't know how this is happen or why I can't call it 2 times on the page.

Comment: Im not sure... :(